# Exclude a word in sql query?

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to write a query in sql to exclude a keyword: 
It's a list of cities written out (e.g. AnnArbor-MI). In the list there are duplicates because some have the word 'badsetup' after the city and these need to be discarded.  How would I write something to exclude any city with 'badsetup' after it?

Answer (score 1):

Your question title and content appear to be asking for two different things ...

Query cities while excluding the trailing 'badsetup':

```
SELECT regexp_matches(citycolumn, '(.*)badsetup')
FROM mytable;
```

Query cities that don't have the trailing 'badsetup':

```
SELECT citycolumn
FROM mytable
WHERE citycolumn NOT LIKE '%badsetup';
```

Answer (score 0):

In psql, to select rows excluding those with the word 'badsetup' you can use the following:

SELECT * FROM table_name WHERE column NOT LIKE '%badsetup%';

In this case the '%' indicates that there can be any characters of any length in this space. So this query will find any instance of the phrase 'badsetup' in your column, regardless of the characters before or after it.

You can find more information in section 9.7.1 here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html